# How to copy exactly the Doctype, if the Doctype or the included entity isn't known?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, entity, doctype

my challenge today is to find out how to copy the Doctype of a source document.
Ok first that is my source:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<!DOCTYPE XMLBlock SYSTEM "/dtd/XMLBlock.dtd" [
<!ENTITY change '<issue>
 <version>VERSION NO: 98765432</version>
   <purpose><![CDATA[
     Main purpose
      - to do things
      - to fix issues ]]>
   </purpose>
 </issue> '>]>
<XMLBlock>
  <Title>XML Stuff</Title>
  <Content>DemoText</Content>
</XMLBlock>
```

As you can see there is an internal entity with a version no, which changes every time. Now I want to catch this number to decide which wrapper is needed.
So this is my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output doctype-system="/dtd/XMLBlock.dtd" />
  <xsl:template match ="/" >
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="&change;/issue/version &lt; 9000000">
          <XMLBlock>
            <red>
              <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
            </red>
          </XMLBlock>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <XMLBlock>
            <green>
               <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
            </green>
          </XMLBlock>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this &change; isn't resolved because it is not a part of the xslt.
So how can I solve the issue, or is it just impossible?
Kind regards

Markus

Answer (score 0):

The XSLT does not have a declaration of the entity `&changed;` so it is not valid XML, as you already know. The stylesheet itself is fixed, the variable part is solely the transformed document.

The parsed XML seen by the transformer also does not have any information about the version value. So it seems pretty useless to declare it as entity.

Seems that your version number would be better stored in a processing instruction:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE XMLBlock SYSTEM "/dtd/XMLBlock.dtd"]>
<?version 98765432?>
<XMLBlock> ...
```

In the stylesheet it is then easy to access the version:

```
<xsl:variable name="version" select="/processing-instruction('version')"/>
```

Comment: Ok ... yes for that simple content like a string I agree but, I also have content like that: '<ct><purpose><![CDATA[module for some 'stuff'     abc ]]> </purpose></ct>

Comment: @markus0074 better to put this in the question. Its also frustrating to answer a question just to receive a comment that the real situation is more complicated.